# Labels not aligning properly in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, orientation, coordinates

Is the code below correct? When the user rotates the device, two labels are supposed to go to the coordinates given below. It works when the user starts the app in portrait mode, the labels are placed correctly. However, when the user starts in landscape mode, the labels DO NOT get placed correctly. But if you rotate the view to portrait and then back to landscape, they align properly. I've tried placing the landscape coordinates in viewDidLoad, and it still doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks for your help!

The two labels are recordingTimeLabel and recordingTimeLabelMinutes.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

 if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
     //is landscape

     backGround.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

     recordingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(967, 22);
     recordingTimeLabelMinutes.center = CGPointMake(901, 22);

     NSLog(@"is landscape");

     //  fixedSpace.width = 400;

 } else {
     //is portrait

     backGround.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

     recordingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(710, 22);
     recordingTimeLabelMinutes.center = CGPointMake(661, 22);

     NSLog(@"is portrait");

 }



}
```

Additionally, this code doesn't work either:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {        
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) {
    //is landscape

    backGround.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

    recordingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(967, 22);
    recordingTimeLabelMinutes.center = CGPointMake(901, 22);

    NSLog(@"is landscape");

} else {
    //is portrait

    backGround.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    recordingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(710, 22);
    recordingTimeLabelMinutes.center = CGPointMake(661, 22);

    NSLog(@"is portrait");

}

}
```

Comment: Btw, in the log is landscape is printed first, and then immediately after is portrait is printed even though the device was never rotated.

Comment: Additionally, backGround is resized and positioned properly.

Comment: Is `viewWillAppear:` being called twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I used an NSTimer and called a function very often that contained this code:

```
-(void)updateLabelLocation {

    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) {

    recordingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(710, 22);
    recordingTimeLabelMinutes.center = CGPointMake(661, 22);

    } 

}
```

Comment: Exactly and put the code to call the method in viewWillAppear.

Comment: NSTimer? I'm sorry, but this is a *horrible* solution.

Comment: It's the only one I got it to work. I could also call the function after a delay of 0, as that doesn't involve a NSTimer.

Answer (score 1):

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` may not be called if you start in landscape mode. I suggest setting the coordinates in `viewWillAppear:`, not `viewDidLoad`, to figure out the initial orientation (you can use `self.interfaceOrientation` if you have autorotation enabled).

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. Here is my code: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        
    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) {
        //is landscape
                
        recordingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(967, 22);
        recordingTimeLabelMinutes.center = CGPointMake(901, 22);
        
        NSLog(@"is landscape");
        
    } else {
        
    }
        
} I took out the else to save space, it is correct though.

Comment: "Didn't work"? Did it do anything? Please edit that code into the question.

Comment: Yes, put it in. No, there were no results. Again, in the log "is landscape" is shown followed by a "is portrait" even though the device is only in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set following code also for the UIInterfaceOrientation?

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it rotates in all four orientations.